# R cannot be resolved due to an image

Tags: android, android-studio

I have gradle error when I include the image below into the res folder. I have no problem with any other images even after I had rebuild/clean/compile the project. Is there something wrong with the image below?

Thanks you.

[image]

Comment: can i see the name of this image which you gave in drawable folder ??

Comment: Try placing it inside a specific resolution folder like hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi etc

Comment: safety_forklift_diagram. I tried placing each folder but still getting that "R cannot be resolved error".

Comment: dont use the capital letter in image name,rename it.

Comment: you dont have something like `image.jpg` what is the file extension ?? `png` ?? `jpeg` ??

Comment: safety_forklift_diagram.png

Comment: Post your log here.

Comment: Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 6s 640ms

Comment: @K.Liu, your error log.

Comment: AAPT err(Facade for 749616925): libpng error: Not a PNG file

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.35 secs

Comment: I think i know why now........

Answer (score 0):

Try after renaming your image in small case and avoid any special case letter in name and it should not be too long.
Hope this will help.

Comment: all small case and no special case letter. "safety_forklift_diagram"

Comment: even the extension should be in small case like .png NOT .PNG

Comment: yes.. it's all small case "safety_forklift_diagram.png"

Comment: remove _ (underscore) from name and try then

Comment: Still the same error "R cannot be resolved". Does this image work for you?

Comment: try after removing this image and check if that work for you

Comment: "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 6s 640ms." "Cannot resolved symbol R"

Comment: Yes! If i remove this image, i can compile my project. Why?!

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.safety_forklift_diagram);
```

try this..